# Example of non-homeomorphic compact spaces $K_1$ and $K_2$ such that $K_1\oplus K_1$ is homeomorphic to $K_2\oplus K_2$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Once I heard that there exists two compact spaces $K_1$ and $K_2$ which are non-homeomorphic, but with $K_1\oplus K_1$ homeomorphic to $K_2\oplus K_2$ (where $\oplus$ denotes the topological sum).

Is it true?

Comment: what is the topological sum? Do you mean disjoint union?

Comment: That's interesting, I hope somebody can come up with a good answer.

Comment: @oxeimon: The discrete union.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If it means disjoint union then it seems shocking that the result is true.

Comment: Yes, I meant the disjoint union.

Answer (score 7):

K. Sundaresan, *Banach spaces with Banach-Stone property*, in *Studies in Topology* (N.M. Stavrakas & K.R. Allen, eds.), Academic Press, New York, $1975$, pp. $573$-$580$, contains an example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that if $Y$ and $Z$ are the results of adding one and two isolated points, respectively, to $X$, then $X\cong Z\not\cong Y$, where $\cong$ denotes homeomorphism. Thus, $X\oplus X\cong X\oplus Z\cong Y\oplus Y$, even though $X\not\cong Y$. In *On an example of Sundaresan*, Topology Proceedings, Vol. $5$ ($1980$), pp. $185$-$186$, I gave a simpler proof of some of the properties of $X$; this paper is freely available [here](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v05/tp05014.pdf) [PDF].

Briefly, $X$ is obtained by pasting together the remainders of two copies of $\beta\omega$ in the natural way. Let $X=\omega^*\cup(\omega\times 2)$, where $\omega^*=\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, and let $\pi:X\to\beta\omega$ be the obvious projection; the topology on $X$ is the coarsest making $\pi$ continuous and each point of $N=\omega\times 2$ isolated. For $i\in 2$ let $N_i=\omega\times\{i\}$. Intuitively $Y$, obtained by adding an isolated point to $X$, is not homeomorphic to $X$ *because* the extra point must be added to one of the ‘tails’ $N_0$ and $N_1$, and this ‘skews’ the pasting-together of the two copies of $\omega^*$ to form $X$; in $Z$, on the other hand, we can think of one of the new points as extending $N_0$ and the other, $N_1$, so that the two copies of $\omega^*$, being similarly ‘shifted’, still line up correctly. The actual argument can be found in the linked paper.

Comment: @Luis: An ordinal is the set of smaller ordinals, so $\omega=[0,\omega)$. You can replace $\omega$ everywhere by $\Bbb N$ if you like (bearing in mind that for me $\Bbb N$ includes $0$).

Comment: $\pi$ is such that $\pi|_{\beta\omega\setminus\omega}=id$ and $\pi((n,i))=n$, for all $n\in\omega$ and $i=0,1$.
The accumulation point $\omega$ is in $\beta\omega$.
We build a basis in $X$ containing:
(i) the open sets of $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ not containing $\omega$;
(ii) the sets $\{(k,0):k\geq n_0\}\cup\{(k,1):k\geq n_1\}\cup W$, for each $n_0,n_1\in\omega$ and $W\subset\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ open neighborhood of $\omega$.
(iii) the sets $\{(n,i)\}$, for each $n\in\omega$ and $i\in2$.
This topology is the coarsest satisfying the properties we wish.
Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @Luis: No, because there is no point of $\beta\omega$ corresponding to the ordinal $\omega$. $\beta\omega$ (or $\beta\Bbb N$) is the [Čech-Stone compactification](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of the discrete space of natural numbers. If you're not familiar with it, you'll probably have a hard time making much sense of the example.

Comment: I do have a bit of familiarity with Cech-Stone compactification. I will be working on it. But, at least, is it $\pi$, as I described in the previous comment, the correct projection?

Comment: @Luis: Yes, that's the correct map.