# Finding a type such that $X + 1 \not\simeq X$ and $X+2\simeq X$

Tags: logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

Yesterday, I read the following question : [Finding a space such that $X\cong X+2$ and $X\not\cong X+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577214/finding-a-space-with-x-cong-x2-and-x-not-cong-x1), and found the result very astounding.

Does it still hold in homotopy type theory? As a type theorist, I don't really understand the answer…

I tried to redo the proof, translating it in type-theoretic words, but and I don't seem to find a description of Stone-Čech compactification easily translatable to HoTT.

Is there an analogous of SČ-compactification in homotopy type theory (or at least, a description of $\beta\mathbb N$)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in HoTT a type is simply a space, and equivalence of types is simply homotopy equivalence of spaces, right? So what makes you think that result holds "in topology" but not "in HoTT"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Actually, a type is more a infinity-groupoid than a space, so some results true in usual topology might be false in HoTT, or at least need a generalization

Comment: I've always been taught that an $\infty$-groupoid is "the same thing" as a space (there's a Quillen equivalence, so from the point of view of homotopy there's not much difference). Can you give an example of a result (of a similar nature as this one) holding in topology but not in HoTT?

Comment: @KevinQuirin - You wrote "$X+1\not\simeq1$ and $X+2\simeq X$", but I suspect you mean "$X+1\not\simeq X$ and $X+2\simeq X$".

Comment: @Najib See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/HomotopyTypeTheory/Wf-H6rH155g for several thoughtful comments on the "space vs. homotopy type" issue.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Ah, I see the problem. I assumed that the question linked at the top was using $\cong$ to denote homotopy equivalence (a rather stupid assumption to be honest, I was probably confused by the context), and that they had constructed a space $X$ such that $X$ was htpy.eq. to $X+2$ but not $X+1$. My mistake. My point (and it's now in Mike Shulman's answer) was that this question is nothing special about HoTT, it's simply a question about spaces and homotopy equivalences of spaces.

Answer (score 5):

The question you linked to is, if I understand it correctly, asking about *homeomorphism* of topological spaces (that's what the symbol $\cong$ usually means).  Types in HoTT behave like $\infty$-groupoids, which can (classically) be presented by topological spaces, but only up to *homotopy equivalence*.  So the first question is whether for the example spaces listed, it might still be the case that $X+1\simeq X$ even though $X+1\not\cong X$.  I don't know.  However, if it does happen that $X+1\not\simeq X$ as well, then it will automatically be true *in the "standard" model of HoTT* (where types are interpreted by classical $\infty$-groupoids) that such a type exists.  However, that is a very different thing from saying that such a type can be *constructed* inside the formal system of HoTT.  In particular, the Stone-Cech compactification is an operation on topological spaces, not on $\infty$-groupoids, so there is no obvious way to give it meaning inside HoTT.

Comment: My bad, I thought at first that the original question was about homotopy equivalence, and then realised my mistake. However, I don't seem to find a reason for such a type not to exist, and my only hint so far is to check whether the homeomorphisms presented can be changed into homotopy equivalences

Comment: @KevinQuirin A homeomorphism is a particular case of homotopy equivalence. What you want to show is that there is no homotopy equivalence $X+1 \simeq X$ (so far all you know is that there's no homeomorphism), not that the homeomorphism $X \cong X+2$ "can be changed into a homotopy equivalence" (which is obvious since it's already one).