# For groups, does $G \times G \cong H\times H$ imply $G \cong H$?

Tags: group-theory

By Remak's theorem, this is true for finite groups, and so any counter example would counter Remak so is probably nontrivial.

Comment: @Orat I'm not familiar with it, but looking in wikipedia it's the same proof of Remak just noticing it works in greater generality, but not for all groups...

Comment: Do you mean the Cartesian product? For non-abelian groups it seems weird to talk about direct sums.

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes, i mean the product then (didn't know the notation)

Comment: For the same question for rings, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869512/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. According to the answers to [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3) (also [this other one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793/if-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-then-is-g-cong-h) as pointed out in a comment by Orat), there is a countable Abelian group $A$ such that $A^2\not\cong A\cong A^3.$ Let $G=A$ and let $H=A^2.$ Then $G$ and $H$ are countable Abelian groups such that $G\times G\cong H\times H\cong H$ while $G\not\cong H.$

Comment: See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793/if-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-then-is-g-cong-h) which is regarded as a duplicate of this but asking exactly the same.

Comment: @Orat Thanks. I added that reference to my answer.

Comment: As a follow up, what if we know $G^n=H^n$ for all $n>1$? This amounts to knowing it for $n=2,n=3$. This example doesn't generalize

Comment: Is there any *concrete* specification of $A$ readily available?