# If $X$ is homeomorphic to subset of set $Y$ and $Y$ is homeomorphic to subset of $X$ then are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau_1)$ and $(Y, \tau_2)$ be topological spaces. Is it true that if $X$ is homeomoprhic to a subset of $Y$ and $Y$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $X$ then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic spaces?

I'm trying to find a counter-example cause I don't believe that the statement is correct, however I'm struggling since I don't know that many homeomorphisms. An idea I had is to prove that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the other way around but $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: The plane is not homeomorphic to any subset of the line.

Comment: The simplest example is probably $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\;[0.2,\,0.7]\subseteq (0,1)=:X\;$ is homemomorphic to $\;Y:=[0,1]\;$ , and $\;(0.2,\,0.7)\subseteq Y\;$ is homeomorphic to $\;X\;$ , but ...

Answer (score 2):

It is even possible to find a compact Hausdorff space $X$ with the following property, though the example is a bit complicated:

> If $Y$ is the space obtained from $X$ by adding a single isolated point, then $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic, $X$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $Y$, and $Y$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $X$.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303459/example-of-non-homeomorphic-compact-spaces-k-1-and-k-2-such-that-k-1-oplus/1304838#1304838) and the PDF linked from it.